# Switch true for min and max range in power bi desktop

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, max, dax, min

I am trying to specify each dimension range (length, width and height) of values specify criteria based on the length, width and height.

In data table I have 3 columns are length, width,height based on the 3 columns I would like to generate status columns which is based on the below mentioned condition range.

**Conditions Range**

1. Length, width and height is start from 1 to 300 then  A1.
2. Length, width and height is start from 301 to 650 then A2.
3. Length, width and height is start from 651 to 900 then A3.
4. Length, width and height is start from 901 to 1200 then A4
5. Length, width and height is start from 1201 above then XXX

**Data**

| LENGTH | WIDTH | HEIGHT | DESIRED RESULT RANGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 20000 | 5000 | 230 | XX |
| 400 | 300 | 140 | A1 |
|  |  |  | BLANKS |
| 600 | 400 | 285 | A2 |
| 600 | 400 | 285 | A2 |
| 400 | 300 | 150 | A1 |
| 280 | 230 | 170 | A1 |
| 320 | 320 | 320 | A1 |
| 320 | 320 | 320 | A1 |
| 600 | 400 | 140 | A1 |
| 400 | 300 | 140 | A1 |
| 400 | 300 | 140 | A1 |
| 370 | 320 | 340 | A1 |
| 320 | 240 | 250 | A1 |
| 300 | 200 | 90 | A1 |
| 400 | 290 | 140 | A1 |
| 600 | 400 | 285 | A1 |

**Table and result look like**

[image]

Any suggestions please

Comment: Your result doesn't seem like follow a same logic? For example, why row 10 is `A1` when all the value are above 300, but row 7 is `A2` when one of the value is below 300 ??

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I prepare the desired result manually so I made a mistake. Could you please provide solution

Comment: if `lengh & width` above 700 but `height` is below 300, what is the result, as your criteria does not mention `else` factor, since it only cover when both three criteria is meet then only return one value, but not when `only two meet` and one of them `does not meet`?

Comment: that's ture. If doesn't meet the range of criteria then please mark "?" if its possible so I will modify my range later so it will cover some value. Thank you.

Comment: I understand your point most of them not covering range of criteria but I will change it later according to my actual range of criteria. I would like to know how can I do it in power bi then I will modify the formula later. I am looking for new calculate column option. Can you please advise when you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may try the following dax measure, as it will assign all row to each category, and assign to `Other` if does not match any of the criteria, do take note due to your data contain `NA`, therefore all the value is in `Text` for that need to convert to number during calculation:

```
Result = IF(Sheet1[LENGTH] = "NA" || Sheet1[WIDTH] = "NA" || Sheet1[HEIGHT] ="NA", "NA",
            IF(VALUE(Sheet1[LENGTH])>0 && VALUE(Sheet1[LENGTH]) <=300 && VALUE(Sheet1[WIDTH]) >0 && VALUE(Sheet1[WIDTH]) <=300 && VALUE(Sheet1[HEIGHT]) >0 && VALUE(Sheet1    [HEIGHT]) <=300, "A1",

                IF(VALUE(Sheet1[LENGTH])>300 && VALUE(Sheet1[LENGTH]) <=650 && VALUE(Sheet1[WIDTH]) >300 && VALUE(Sheet1[WIDTH]) <=650 && VALUE(Sheet1[HEIGHT]) >300 && VALUE    (Sheet1[HEIGHT]) <=650, "A2",

                IF(VALUE(Sheet1[LENGTH])>650 && VALUE(Sheet1[LENGTH]) <=900 && VALUE(Sheet1[WIDTH]) >650 && VALUE(Sheet1[WIDTH]) <=900 && VALUE(Sheet1[HEIGHT]) >650 && VALUE    (Sheet1[HEIGHT]) <=900, "A3",

                    IF(VALUE(Sheet1[LENGTH])>900 && VALUE(Sheet1[LENGTH]) <=1200 && VALUE(Sheet1[WIDTH]) >900 && VALUE(Sheet1[WIDTH]) <=1200 && VALUE(Sheet1[HEIGHT]) >900 &&    VALUE(Sheet1[HEIGHT]) <=1200, "A4",

                        IF(VALUE(Sheet1[LENGTH])>1200 && VALUE(Sheet1[WIDTH]) >1200  && VALUE(Sheet1[HEIGHT]) >1200 , "XXX",
                            "Others"))))))
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help and explaining the notes as well. Is this measure or DAX new calculate column. Can you please advise. I am looking for new calculate column option.

Comment: It is an add column measure, the result is in original data table, accept the answer if helping :)